# CNTK: /home/me/opencv-3.0.0/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:46:28: opencv/core.hpp: No such file or directory

Tags: opencv, cntk

I have got an error while building cntk with make all -j4.

As specified in the title the error was:

```
/home/me/opencv-3.0.0/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:46:28: opencv/core.hpp: No such file or directory
```

I followed instructions [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/Setup-CNTK-on-Linux) and, I have no clue as to what has caused the error. I have also asked this question [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/issues/483) so, please follow that too.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

This maybe caused by wrong version (opencv-3.1.0) or installation path, as the guide says "IMPORTANT! Install OpenCV using the exact version and target path as specified below. This is necessary because it is expected by the CNTK build configuration program." in the [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/Setup-CNTK-on-Linux).